# Using LESSPHP, passing variables as arguments into Mixins

Tags: less

V: lessphp v0.3.4-2

Using this:

```
@topDarkGrey: #6e6c74;
@bottomDarkGrey: #5d5b64;

.gradient (@startColor: #eee, @endColor: white) {
    background-color: @startColor;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
}

    background: .gradient(@topDarkGrey, @bottomDarkGrey);
```

I receive:

```
lessphp fatal error: parse error: failed at `background: .gradient(@topDarkGrey, @bottomDarkGrey);
```

Anyone see any problems with this?

Comment: Can u provide more information on this ?

Comment: @Makesh Sure. Edited above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this:

```
background: .gradient(@topDarkGrey, @bottomDarkGrey);
```

Should be this:

```
.gradient(@topDarkGrey, @bottomDarkGrey);
```